# Extract pattern using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the following strings:

```
Name-AB_date, Name-XYZ_date, Name-JK_date, Name-AB_gate_date, Name-XYZ_gate_date, Name-JK_gate_date
```

I need a regex in PHP that will match the following substrings in each of the above strings

```
AB, XYZ, JK, AB, XYZ, JK
```

I am currently using this the `regex`:

```
(?<=Name-)(.*)(?=_)
```

However in the case of

```
Name-AB_gate_date, Name-XYZ_gate_date and Name-JK_gate_date
```

It is returning

```
AB_gate, XYZ_gate and JK_gate
```

How do I get it to just match the following in these three strings?

AB, XYZ and JK

Permlink: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/96Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` is greedy by default. Change `.*` in your regex to `.*?`. You could try this regex also,

```
(?<=Name-)[^_]*(?=_)
```

OR

Without lookahead.

```
(?<=Name-)[^_]*
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need do is to make the `(.*)` non-greedy.

```
(?<=Name-)(.*?)(?=_)
```

Answer (score 1):

How would it be with

```
Name-(\w*?)_
```

If that fits your needs?

EDIT:

```
Name-(\w+?)_
```

If there must be more than one character.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

```
Name-([^_]*)_.*
```